# How can I configure webpack 2.2.0 rc3 (rc4) and bootstrap alpha 6 via bootstrap-loader

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-4, extract-text-plugin

How can show a right webpack 2 rc3 configuration with bootstap 4?

Here is my [.bootstraprc](https://gist.github.com/IvanKalinin/92bdc83472bd685768e0ddd23e3712a2)

This is my [webpack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/IvanKalinin/7a12dfca10573ff4e94a0d726dd7d329)

And after all I get this error on npm start:

> Error in
>   ./~/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js?{"omit":1,"remove":true}!./~/style-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.styles.loader.js?{"bootstrapVersion":4,"extractStyles":true,"styleLoaders":["style-loader","css-loader","postcss-loader","sass-loader"],"styles":["mixins","normalize","print","reboot","type","images","code","grid","tables","forms","buttons","transitions","dropdown","button-group","input-group","custom-forms","nav","navbar","card","breadcrumb","pagination","jumbotron","alert","progress","media","list-group","responsive-embed","close","badge","modal","tooltip","popover","carousel","utilities"],"scripts":false,"configFilePath":"/Users/ivan/Dev/react/.bootstraprc","bootstrapPath":"/Users/ivan/Dev/react/~/bootstrap","bootstrapRelPath":"../bootstrap"}!./~/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js
>   Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'path' of undefined    @
>   ./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.loader.js?extractStyles!./~/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js
>   1:21-1040   @ ./~/bootstrap-loader/extractStyles.js   @ multi app
>
> Error in
>   ./~/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js?{"omit":1,"remove":true}!./~/style-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.styles.loader.js?{"bootstrapVersion":4,"extractStyles":true,"styleLoaders":["style-loader","css-loader","postcss-loader","sass-loader"],"styles":["mixins","normalize","print","reboot","type","images","code","grid","tables","forms","buttons","transitions","dropdown","button-group","input-group","custom-forms","nav","navbar","card","breadcrumb","pagination","jumbotron","alert","progress","media","list-group","responsive-embed","close","badge","modal","tooltip","popover","carousel","utilities"],"scripts":false,"configFilePath":"/Users/ivan/Dev/react/.bootstraprc","bootstrapPath":"/Users/ivan/Dev/react/~/bootstrap","bootstrapRelPath":"../bootstrap"}!./~/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js
>   Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'path' of undefined   at Object.
>   (/Users/ivan/Dev/react/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2234:31)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed my issues.
The problem was in webpack.config.js

How it was:

```
new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
...
  options: {
    ...
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
    ...
  },
...
})
```

How should it be

```
new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
...
  options: {
    ...
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
    output: {
      path: 'dist',
    },
    ...
  },
...
})
```